# Generating a decrementing ID while inserting data on a Teradata table

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to insert data from a query (or a volatile table) to another table  which has a id column ( with only type smallint and not null constraint) which should be unique, on Teradata using teradata SQL Assistant the min(id) = -5 and i should insert the new data with a lower id.

This is a simple example:

table a

```
id|  aa  |bb
-3|text  |text_2
-5|text_3|text_4
```

and the data i should insert is for example :

```
 aa   |  bb
text_5|text_6
text_7|text_8
text_9|text_10
```

so the result should be like

```
    id|  aa  |bb
    -3|text  |text_2
    -5|text_3|text_4
    -6|text_5|text_6
    -7|text_7|text_8
    -8|text_9|text_10
```

I tried to pass by creating volatile table with a generated id start by -5 increment by -1 no cycle.

But I get an error

> Expected something like a name or a unicode delimited identifier or a cycle keyword between an integer and ','

There is any other way to do it please ?

Comment: Your syntax seems to be wrong, but an identity on a smallint column will not work as expected anyway. You can easily calculate it in your Select using `-5 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aa)`

Comment: The correct syntax is `id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                   (START WITH -6
                    INCREMENT BY -1)`

Comment: thank you, i used the first solution ( because i know the min(id) otherwise i can't find a solution)